# Homeomorphism: can $f:X\mapsto X'$ be continuous, bijective without $f^{-1}:X'\mapsto X$ being continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In our definition of homeomorphic topological spaces there must exist a bijective function $f:X\mapsto X'$ such that $f$ is continuous on $X$ and $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $X'$.

Is it necessary to assure that $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $X'$?

Comment: Sure. Take the identity on $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology onto $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement that 
$f^{-1}$ is continuous, is essential. Consider for instance the function 
$f:[0,2 \pi)\rightarrow S_1$ (the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$f(\phi )=(\cos \phi ,\sin \phi ))$.

This function is bijective and continuous, but not a homeomorphism ($S^{1}$ is compact but $[0,2\pi )$ is not).

The function 
$f^{-1}$ is not continuous at the point 
$(1,0)$, because although 
$f^{-1}$ maps 
$(1,0)$ to 
$0$, any neighbourhood of this point also includes points that the function maps close to 
$2\pi $, but the points it maps to numbers in between lie outside the neighbourhood.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assume this, it is not automatic:

If $X=\{1,2\}$ in the discrete topology and $Y=X$ in the indiscrete/trivial topology, then $f(x)=x$ is continuous from $X$ to $Y$ but its inverse (the same identity) is not continuous from $Y$ to $X$.